# How to interpret $a_i^k g_{kj}g^{jl}$? (Tensor index notation)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

I have the equation $$a_i^k g_{kj}=-b_{ij},$$ where $a_i^k$ are given by: $a_i^k \cdot\vec r_k=\vec n_i$.

Here, $g_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are the matrices that determine the first and second fundamental form respectively. So $g_{ij}=\langle \vec r_i,\vec r_j\rangle $ and $b_{ij}=\langle \vec r_{ij},\vec n\rangle$, where $\vec r_{i}=\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial x_i}$.

My text says: We now multiply both sides with the inverse matrix $g^{jl}$ to get $$a^l_i=-b_{ij}g^{jl}=-b_i^l.$$

Here's what I understand/assume to be true:

- Summation signs are ommited
- $g^{jl}:=(g_{lj})^{-1}$, where $g_{lj}$ is a matrix.
- $i,j,k,l$ all run from $1$ to $n$, so we should have $g_{kj}g^{jl}=\mathrm{Id}_n$

So I say $$a_i^kg_{kj}g^{jl}=\begin{pmatrix}a_i^1g_{11}&\cdots &a_i^1g_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_i^ng_{n1}& \cdots & a_i^ng_{nn}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}g_{11}&\cdots &g_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
g_{n1}& \cdots &g_{nn}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_i^1& & & \\ & a_i^2& & \\ & & \ddots & \\
 & & & a_i^n\end{pmatrix}}_*.$$

So did I calculate $a_i^kg_{kj}g^{jl}$ correctly? I'm not sure, because I assumed the $a_i^k$'s are scalars, so saying $a_i^l=*$, wouldn't make much sense.

---

I hope it's clear that I am having trouble with the notation that is used.

Comment: It's more natural to regard $a$ as a mixed tensor than as a collection of $n$ vectors indexed by $i$. Since $a$ has type $(1, 1)$, we can represent it as a matrix in its own right, with $(k, i)$ entry $a^k{}_i$. Then, we can write the contraction as $g^{lj} g_{jk} a^k{}_i$. If we choose a basis, the resulting tensor has matrix representation given by the product of the matrices of the three tensors in the contraction: $[g]^{-1} [g] [a]$, but $[g]^{-1}[g]=I_n$, so the matrix representation of the contraction is just $[a]$ again, and this time we denote its indices by the dummy variables $i,l$.

Comment: Notice that we rearranged the three tensors in the contraction so that the paired indices are adjacent: This is precisely what we need so that the contraction is given by usual matrix multiplication. NB that in order to arrange this, we had to write $g_{kj}$ as $g_{jk}$ (and likewise with $g^{jl}$), which we can do precisely because $g$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Travis Does this mean we might as well say that $a_i^kg_{kj}g^{jl}=a_i^k$, since it doesn't matter what name we asign to our variables?

Comment: @Travis Also, when the text says $a_i^l=-b_i^l$, is it then just defining what $b_i^l$ is?

Comment: @Travis Might I suggest you turn your comment(s) into an answer.